# Blacking out regexp in pdf files from command line

Tags: command-line, pdf

Is there any command line tool (or toolchain) for linux where I can automatically blackout a given regexp in a pdf, or alternatively (maybe better) introduce noise in the match to make the parts matching the regexp unreadable in the pdf.

Currently I use gimp and do it manually, but this is very annoying and I am looking for a way to automate it (and one step further use it in a script).

Comment: Is that for printing, or are you going to distribute the PDF file? If you distribute the PDF file, you can't just hide something by putting a black rectangle on it: the text is still in the file. It can only work if you fully rasterize, which has many downsides: it makes the file bigger, makes the quality less good, removes hyperlinks, makes the file non-searchable, makes it inaccessible to blind people, …

Comment: Just for printing.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with various levels of success depending on how complex the formatting of the PDF file is.

Start by converting the PDF file to HTML using Poppler's `pdftohtml`:

```
pdftohtml -noframes -s <input.pdf>
```

Obscure specific text using your regexp:

```
sed -i 's/<regexp>/<replacement>/g' <input.html>
```

Convert HTML file back to PDF:

```
wkhtmltopdf --no-background --enable-local-file-access <input.html> <output.pdf>
```

You may have to play around with various options in `wkhtmltopdf` to adjust page margins, size and orientation, etc. See `man wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: If the pdf is a scanned document (with ocr layer) this results probably in a html file including the original pdf as image and thus doesn't work. In other cases the format may be screwed up by the html conversion.

Comment: I think the solution should work somehow with the ocr layer which contains information about the position of the matches.